# Quantum error correction and graph codes

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, quantum-computing, coding-theory, combinatorics

I was reading [combinatorial approach towards quantum correction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6743). A lot of work in this is on finding diagonal distance of a graph. Let me add definition of diagonal distance so that this remains self-contained.

Given a labeling $L$ (a map where each vertex is is assigned 1 or 0) we define two operations on this:

1. $X(v,L)$: you flip labeling of vertex v that is if it was zero make it 1 if it was 1 make it 0.
2. $Z(v,L)$: you flip labeling of every neighbor of vertex v

Then diagonal distance is defined as length of minimal non-trivial sequence of operation so that $L$ is taken back to itself.

How is this exactly related to the quantum error correction property?

Comment: This question has been answered on the [quantum computing se](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/12793/quantum-error-correcting-codes-and-graphs).

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/47049/5038, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12793/510.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. I waited for couple of weeks and it was not answered, so my understanding was that after clearly mentioning that it cross-posted one can do this. I think 2 weeks was good time for this. Let me know if there is a better way to do this.